# WordPress: Remove application/ld+json from head tag

Tags: wordpress

How to remove script tag shown bellow from the wordpress page using php or javascript.

```
<script type="application/ld+json">{"@context":"http:\/\/schema.org","@type":"BlogPosting","mainEntityOfPage":"http:\/\/domain.com\/190415-%d8%a5%d8%b0%d8%a7-%d9%83%d9%86%d8%aa-%d8%aa%d9%86%d9%88%d9%8a-%d8%b2%d9%8a%d8%a7%d8%b1%d8%a9-%d8%a3%d9%88%d8%b1%d9%88%d8%a8%d8%a7-%d9%87%d8%b0%d8%a7-%d8%a7%d9%84%d8%b5%d9%8a%d9%81%d8%8c-%d8%ad%d8%b3%d8%a7%d8%a8%d8%a7%d8%aa-%d8%a7%d9%86%d8%b3%d8%aa%d9%82%d8%b1%d8%a7%d9%85-%d9%87%d8%b0%d9%87-%d8%b3%d8%aa%d9%83%d9%88%d9%86-%d8%af%d9%84%d9%8a%d9%84%d9%83\/","publisher":{"@type":"Organization","name":"\u0634\u0628\u0643\u0629 \u0623\u0628\u0648 \u0646\u0648\u0627\u0641","logo":{"@type":"ImageObject","url":"http:\/\/domain.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/02\/favicon.png","height":32,"width":32}},"headline":"\u0625\u0630\u0627 \u0643\u0646\u062a \u062a\u0646\u0648\u064a \u0632\u064a\u0627\u0631\u0629 \u0623\u0648\u0631\u0648\u0628\u0627 \u060c \u062d\u0633\u0627\u0628\u0627\u062a \u0627\u0646\u0633\u062a\u0642\u0631\u0627\u0645 \u0633\u062a\u0643\u0648\u0646 \u062f\u0644\u064a\u0644\u0643","datePublished":"2015-04-20T19:14:41+00:00","dateModified":"2016-02-01T11:12:42+00:00","author":{"@type":"Person","name":"\u0645\u062d\u0631\u0631\u0661"},"image":{"@type":"ImageObject","url":"http:\/\/domain.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2015\/04\/Europ.jpg","width":950,"height":534}}</script>
```

From `Head` tag.

How can do that

Answer (score 0):

Depends on where the tag gets injected. Check you header.php file in Theme directory, if it's not the one, try disabling all plugins one by one to see which one adds that tag.

Comment: Than it has to be in your theme. A simple search inside the php files of your theme will reveal that for sure.

Comment: Imposible to help you without having access to your server.

Comment: i cannot send my server access to you :-)

Comment: I'm not asking these.. ;-) I'm just saying that it's not possible to help you without actually going thru the files.